# Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit closes/recreates Source connection when Sink binder is down

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

When one of publisher binder is down, SCS is closing existing connection to rabbit1 server, is it expected?

Our processor application connects to two binder's [rabbit1 and rabbit2]
rabbit1 is our SOURCE for events and rabbit2 is SINK for processed events.

following are configs:

```
#rabbit1
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.type=rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.default-candidate=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.inherit-environment=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitserver1.hostname.com
#rabbit2
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit2.type=rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit2.default-candidate=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit2.inherit-environment=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit2.environment.spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitserver2.un-available.com

# ----------------------------------------------------
#|        consumer properties                         |
# ----------------------------------------------------
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.caInput.binder=rabbit1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.caInput.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.caInput.group=event.source.queue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caInput.consumer.bindQueue=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caInput.consumer.declareExchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caInput.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caInput.consumer.prefetch=30
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caInput.consumer.acknowledge-mode=MANUAL
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caInput.consumer.max-concurrency=2
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caInput.consumer.consumer-tag-prefix=custom-consumer-tag
# ----------------------------------------------------
#|        producer properties                         |
# ----------------------------------------------------
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.caOutput.binder=rabbit2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.caOutput.destination=exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.caOutput.group=publisher-queue-group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.caOutput.producer.required-groups=publisher-queue-group
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caOutput.producer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.caOutput.producer.exchange-type=fanout
```

while testing scenario where rabbit1 is up and rabbit2 is down, I see that SCS is closing existing connections to rabbit1

```java
@EnableBinding({ AppBinder.class })
public class Processor {

    @StreamListener(target = AppBinder.INPUT, copyHeaders = "false")
    @SendTo(AppBinder.OUTPUT)
    public String consumeEvents(@Payload String message, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(message);
        channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
        return "test response";
    }

    @StreamListener("errorChannel")
    public void error(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("Handling ERROR: " + message);
    }

    public interface AppBinder {
        /**
         * Input channel name
         */
        final String INPUT = "caInput";
        /**
         * Name of the output channel.
         */
        final String OUTPUT = "caOutput";

        /**
         * @return output channel which is connected to rabbit2 binder
         */
        @Output(OUTPUT)
        MessageChannel publish();

        /**
         * @return input channel which is connected to rabbit1 binder
         */
        @Input(INPUT)
        MessageChannel consume();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't think of anything in the framework that would do that; please post DEBUG logs someplace like pastebin or a GitHub Gist (or here if it's small enough) that exhibit this behavior.

Comment: you are right @GaryRussell, framework is not closing/recreating connections, it does try to create publisher connection to rabbit1 [source] binder


`2020-05-30 18:02:59.614  INFO 20768 --- [e.queue.dev01-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory.publisher#457cf5b2:0/SimpleConnection@f4ac798 [delegate=amqp://rabbituser@rabbit1ip:5672/, localPort= 62445]`


If SOURCE ack-mode is manual, are we supposed to create publisher connection to source?

please let me know if you would like me to post logs